# How adjust image in java that open by default taking the computer resolution automatically

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, resolution

A image is read and is displayed as splash before the actual things come out. Now problem is that i want to fix the resolution of image accroding to the computer in which it get executed. How this can be done?

Code is as below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FrmSplash extends JWindow implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        JLabel SplashLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Image001.jpg"));

            Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    getContentPane().add(SplashLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setLocation((screen.width),(screen.height));
    show();
}
}
```

This on compilation give following error Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Again compiled with -Xlint but more sorts of errors.

Answer (score 5):

Use this: `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()`

Answer (score 4):

this is about method `show();`, is long time `depreciated`, use `setVisible()` instead, code could be

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FrmSplash extends JWindow implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run() {
        JLabel SplashLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Image001.jpg"));
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        getContentPane().add(SplashLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize((screen.width), (screen.height));
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean setSize instead of setLocation?

Comment: after seeing correct answer by @StanislavL I answered only `Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details`

Comment: I read the post too fast and missed that the OP had posted that code. Anyway, this setLocation looks wrong to me. Cheers.

Comment: @mKorbel Your code is good but problem is that image is not get leaded instead the main content open taking the same time as before.